# Degrees Minutes Seconds to Decimal degrees for Iceland coordinates - Normal formulas come out wrong

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel

I want to put a file with Coordinates in Minutes seconds to decimal degrees.

Ive tried to use formulas such as should work in excel both modules and this formula: =-H2-I2/60-J2/3600 and 65,26583333. As well as tried to use python in ArcGis. None of them work and the coordinates end up being close to where they chould be but in the sea.

I can see that the coordinates I have are not wrong because Ive checked there status according to minutes seconds format. One coordinate: 65° 03' 839" 22° 44' 982")

Does anybody know what might be wrong or if Iceland in a north location needs a different formula?

Comment: One minute has only 60 seconds. Your 65° 03' 839 means perhaps 65 degrees and 03.839 minutes (decimal minutes).

Comment: Are you certain on the coordinate that you posted, the: 65° 03' 839" 22° 44' 982" - if so, I believe that your problem may stem from it not actually being deg-min-sec, but actually deg-min.dec, which is a silly variant. A conversion tool that includes deg-min.dec can be found at http://www.directionsmag.com/site/latlong-converter/

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, your problem seems to be with the way the data is formatted.  If you assume the value should be 65º 03.839' 22º 44.982, this mathematically converts (degrees + minutes/60) to 65.06398333333333 22.7497º Both points land on the same spot in the southwest of Iceland.